# Calling a (dynamic) JS function returning a Promise from Kotlin

Tags: javascript, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I'm trying to perform the equivalent of this JS snippet from Kotlin/JS.
myFunction is supposed to return a Promise of Something:

```js
myFunction()
    .then(onSuccess, onFailure);

function onSuccess(something) {
    console.log(something);
}

function onFailure() {
    console.log('Error!');
}
```

How would you do that from Kotlin?

Comment: Kotlin has Promise interop see https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-promise/

Comment: That's Chinese for me at this point. But I think I found a way

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that's obvious for experienced Kotlin Programmers, but here's how I solved it:

```
        myFunction().then {
            something -> onSuccess(something)
        }.catch {
            onFailure()
        }
```

Comment: If you want to send the function name like you do in JS, you can do like `myFunction().then(::onSuccess, ::onFailure)` Note that both onSuccess and onFailure should take 1 argument resultant value and Throwable respectively.